# How to assign an existing ID to a seed file in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a file with a bunch of data that I'm trying to seed into the database and assign it to a cart. I've went ahead and created a cart and I just want to assign everything to a singular cart. The problem is trying to locate where I should actually putting the cart_id. The seed looks like this:

```
 require 'csv'

 csv_text = File.read(Rails.root.join('lib', 'seeds', 'IronGloryInventory.csv'))
 csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1')
 csv.each do |row|
 @product = row.to_hash
 t = Product.new
 t.product_name = row['Product']
 t.sku = row['SKU']
 t.price = row['Price']
 t.year = row['Year']
 t.quantity = row['Available'].gsub(/\:|\D/, '')
 t.size = row['Available'].gsub(/\:|\d/, '')
 t.category = row['Category']
 t.description = row['Description']
 t.save
 puts "#{t.product_name}, #{t.year}, #{t.size}, #{t.category} "
end
```

I've tried putting t.cart_id = 1 under the t = Product.new and I get a NoMethodError.

I've tried putting it above the csv.each do with product.cart_id = 1 and I get a undefined local variable.

I feel like it should actually be in the iteration to assign the id but I can't figure it out.

Cart has an association with product of has_many and Product has the belongs_to. Any direction would be super helpful.

Comment: Does your product model have a cart_id attribute? Can you add your schema file?

Comment: create_table "carts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean "purchase"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "guest_id"
    t.integer "product_id"
    t.index ["guest_id"], name: "index_carts_on_guest_id"
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_carts_on_product_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_carts_on_user_id"
  end

Comment: create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "product_name"
    t.string "sku"
    t.integer "price"
    t.integer "year"
    t.boolean "availabilty"
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.string "size"
    t.text "description"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "guest_id"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.string "category"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_products_on_category_id"
    t.index ["guest_id"], name: "index_products_on_guest_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_products_on_user_id"
  end

Comment: Pulled the schema for cart and product.

Comment: There's no `cart_id` in your Product model. Try creating the migration, something like `rails g migration add_cart_to_products cart:references`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `cart_id` attribute in your Product model, that's why the `NoMethodError`.

You can create the corresponding migration to add it, run db:migrate to persist the change in the schema and try again.

```
$ rails g migration add_cart_to_products cart:references
$ rails db:migrate
```

The `product.cart_id` assignation must be within the `each` block otherwise Rails will try to find a local variable called product, that doesn't exist.

```
require 'csv'

csv_text = File.read(Rails.root.join('lib', 'seeds', 'IronGloryInventory.csv'))
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, headers: true, encoding: 'ISO-8859-1')
csv.each do |row|
  product = Product.new
  product.product_name = row['Product']
  product.sku = row['SKU']
  product.price = row['Price']
  product.year = row['Year']
  product.quantity = row['Available'].gsub(/\:|\D/, '')
  product.size = row['Available'].gsub(/\:|\d/, '')
  product.category = row['Category']
  product.description = row['Description']
  product.cart_id = 1
  product.save
  puts "#{product.product_name}, #{product.year}, #{product.size}, #{product.category} "
end
```